# Measure Information content of test samples compared to whole data set

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory, mutual-information

Imagine I am limited to a certain amount of training samples to train a classifier. I am wondering if there is a measure to tell how informative one sample (or a collection of a few samples) of the large data set is compared to the whole data set. Such that you can rate different collections of samples.

I am trying to figure out with such a method if it is possible for example to reduce the large training set to a much smaller one that contains a major fraction of the information and would decrease the training time

For example, I want to classify cars and all the time I see pickups but only a few images of other cars then it might be a good idea to keep the images of all the other cars but drop a few of the pickups. But the question is, is it really a good idea? if yes which images of the pickup do you need to keep and which ones should you drop?

(I don't want to do cross validation, my main interest is not to optimize the classifer...)

One direction might be to have a look at the mutual information. The drawback although is that I would need to estimate a high dimensional distribution, where the dimension depends on the number of features. Any other ideas?

I should maybe point out that I am not interested in the actual training set but want to obtain a score for a given test set, to be able to compare different sets.

Comment: If you have constraint then it's not about goodness of an idea in your example with trucks, it's the only way to go. You need the most informative training sample, but there's no general measure of information that will work for you. You have to come up with your own metric based on the problem.

Comment: Hm I can be more precise maybe you can lead me in a direction (if there is any). The actual problem is: Segmenting an image in background and foreground. To do so I train a random forest classifier on a small subset of pixels that the user annotates. Now I want to measure how good those annotations are compared to the ground truth labels that I have. Because I think that the final output depends not only of the parameters of the model but also on the training set. Hence, I am looking for a quality measure for the smaller training set that the user chooses with respect to the whole data set.

Comment: It sounds like you need some kind of adaptive sampling, then correction of bias created by such scheme. For instance, you focus on observations where you see the biggest difference between ground truth and annotations, and try to pick "similar" observations where the deviations are the biggest